# kendoNumeric format without thousand delimiter

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

How can I remove thousand separator from kendoNumeric?

For example, I would like that number `78820` (which represent Id in DB) is displayed like `78820` and not `78.820` with `format="n0"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use custom numeric format in order to control the thousands delimiter

```
<kendo-numerictextbox
        [format]="'#.##'"
        [value]="5000.12"
></kendo-numerictextbox>
```

Here is a plunkr that demonstrates this setup:

http://plnkr.co/edit/s1xx7MiQwABu2qKKjWIj?p=preview

For more details about the predefined formats, e.g. `n`, `p, check`kendo-intl` documentation. You can find more information about the custom numeric formats there too:

https://github.com/telerik/kendo-intl/blob/develop/docs/num-formatting/index.md